# installing pip in the correct place

Tags: python, django, path, pip

I have pip installed on my machine in the location

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg`

But when I type in

```
$ pip
```

I see the error:

```
//anaconda/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming it's just looking in the wrong place for pip but how can I change where it looks?

Comment: what does `which python` output?

Comment: also what does `echo $PATH` output?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the correct version of pip?

Easiest way to install pip is to download [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) python file. Make sure python is in your path variable. Open a command line prompt and navigate to the where you downloaded the file (get-pip.py).  Type `python get-pip.py` (Note: may need admin rights).

If this was already done correctly make sure the following location "*Your_Python_Install_location*\Scripts" is in your path variable.

For more install info go [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html).